# How to edit company in edit form except for 1 field codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, forms, codeigniter, upload

I have a form for editing my companydata such as: name, country, telephone number, etc...

I also have a form for adding companies to my database. In the addform i have an upload functionality so the company can upload a Logo.

My problem is, when I want to edit the company I've removed the upload function. But when I submit the logo field is set to 0 because I left it empty.

How could I solve this?

I tried something like i`f(isset($this->input->post('logo'))){ some code }else{ 'Logo' => $this->input->post('Logo') };`

My editform looks like this:

```
<?= form_open('members/update/'.$id);?>
<table>
<br/>
<b>NAW Gegevens</b>
    <tr>
    <td><?= form_label('Bedrijfsnaam:');?></td>
    <td><?= form_input('Bedrijfsnaam', $info['Bedrijfsnaam']);?><small> (Spaties niet toegestaan)</small></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td><?= form_label('Adres:');?></td>
    <td><?= form_input('Adres', $info['Adres']);?></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td><?= form_label('Postcode:');?></td>
    <td><?= form_input('Postcode', $info['Postcode']);?></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td><?= form_label('Plaats:');?></td>
    <td><?= form_input('Plaats', $info['Plaats']);?></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td><?= form_label('Telefoonnummer:');?></td>
    <td><?= form_input('Telefoonnummer', $info['Telefoonnummer']);?></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td><?= form_label('Website:');?></td>
    <td><?= form_input('Website', $info['Website']);?></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td><?= form_label('Email:');?></td>
    <td><?= form_input('Email', $info['Email']);?></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td><?= form_label('Profiel:');?></td>
    <td><?= form_textarea('Profiel', $info['Profiel']);?></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td><?= form_label('Categorieen'); ?></td>
    <td><?= form_dropdown('categorieen', $opties); ?></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td><?= form_submit('submit', 'Opslaan');?> <?= form_reset('reset', 'Reset');?></td>
    </tr>


</table>
<?= form_close()?>
```

My controller function:

```
function updatebedrijven()
{
    $dbres = $this->db->get('categorieen');
    $ddmenu = array();
    foreach ($dbres->result_array() as $tablerow) {
        $ddmenu[$tablerow['idcategorieen']] = $tablerow['Categorie'];       
    }
    $data['opties'] = $ddmenu;
    $id = $this->uri->segment(3); 

    $data['info'] = $this->members_model->getbedrijf($id); 
    $data['id'] = $id;
    $this->load->view('members/header');
    $this->load->view('members/editform', $data);
    $this->load->view('members/footer');    
}

function update()
{
    $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
    echo 'id: '.$id;
    $data = array(
       'Bedrijfsnaam' => $this->input->post('Bedrijfsnaam'),
       'Postcode' => $this->input->post('Postcode'),
       'Plaats' => $this->input->post('Plaats'),
       'Telefoonnummer' => $this->input->post('Telefoonnummer'),
       'Email' => $this->input->post('Email'),
       'Website' => $this->input->post('Website'),
       'Profiel' => $this->input->post('Profiel'),
       'Adres' => $this->input->post('Adres'),
       'logo' => $this->input->post('logo')
    );
    $this->members_model->updatebedrijf($id, $data);
    $b = $this->session->userdata('idbedrijven');
    redirect("members/$b");
}
```

How can I make the form remember the current logo when I leave the field empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$this->input->post('logo')` returns `false` if the field is empty or not present (see http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/input.html).

since you update the logo field with the `false` value, it's overridden in the database. check if the field is set before you set this field: `'logo' => $this->input->post('logo')`

you may have a look at http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#update

Comment: I don't know how to work it out that's why I ask the question. i already read the docs about update.

Comment: which database do you use? mysql?

Comment: ok. regarding to the active record docs the code produces this sql command: `UPDATE mytable SET title = '{$title}', name = '{$name}', date = '{$date}' WHERE id = $id`. if you just want to update the title e.g. you don't set the name and date field in the array. so your array looks like `$data = array('title' => $title);`. this produces `UPDATE mytable SET title = '{$title}' WHERE id = $id`.

Comment: so, if you don't want to update the logo field, don't set it in the array.

Comment: Hm yeah. I thought about that too. that works but what if I want to update it?

Comment: the `$this->db->update('mytable', $data);` expects an array as second parameter. so you can set this as you wish. in your case add the logo field to the `$data` array in your controller update function if it exists. this array is given to your model `$this->members_model->updatebedrijf($id, $data);`.

Comment: to clarify: the sql command is automatically produced from the fields you set on your array.

Comment: Without any matching examples I don't get what you mean. I think you understand wrong. I want the file select to skip of it is not updated with a new logo. But it adds 0 to the database now. I just want to skip it when I leave it like it was.

Comment: ok. once again. since you have no logo field in your form, `$this->input->post('logo')` will produce `false`, which is 0 in mysql. if you want to keep your 'old' logo data, do not write the line `'logo' => $this->input->post('logo')` in your data array, since this line will set the logo field to 0. if you remove this line from your array, the logo will NOT be set to 0 (= will not be updated).

Comment: Once again. What if I want to update the logo? I removed the field as a test to see if it worked or not. I want to add that field but want to set a value form the database just like the other fields.

Comment: e.g. you can add this beneath your $data array of your controller update function: `if($this->input->post('logo')) { $data['logo'] = $this->input->post('logo'); }`. this will update the logo field if it's SET otherwise NOT.